# Equals() returns false on 'Y' but returns true on 'Yes'

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

I'm doing an if statement in mybatis, and `<if test="param.equals('Y')">` returns false even when the param is "Y", but  `<if test="param.equals('Yes')">` returns true when the param is "Yes", why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you're trying to compare string with char, would you please do that instead

```
<if test='param.equals("Y")'>
```

or you can use == in mybatis so in this case the statement would be

```
<if test="param == 'Y'">
```

Comment: And `<if test='param == "Y"'>`?

Comment: exactly, in sql side, you're totally in the mybatis' territory so there may not be support for all java-side methods, it'd be beneficial to use "==" for comparisons since they do alike this in their website

Comment: With `<if test='param == "Y"'>` , it gives Cause: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"Y\"\r\n### error. But `<if test='param.equals("Y")'>` worked! thank you